# I am getting error "An error occurred when executing a flow interview" in process builder

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, process-builder

I am trying to call a Autolaunched Flow from Process. In flow I have two elements, that the first element to call apex method with passing few parameters from flow to perform logic and updating records. After completion of this the second element will send email.

When I insert/update a record from UI its working fine without error. When I try to insert bunch of records from developer console its throwing error from process builder.

Error:
Encountered unhandled fault when running process Rollup_Process_with_Flow/30124000000PJwI exception by user/organization: 00D2400000*****/{4}

An error occurred when executing a flow interview.

caused by element : FlowActionCall.myRule_1_A1

caused by: An error occurred when executing a flow interview.

Any idea on this error ?

Comment: You will need to add logs to debug .Also try removing elements from one by one to figure root cause of issue .Thanks

Comment: I checked with debug log. From debug log only I got to know that the error is coming from process not in flow.

Comment: Share your code ?

Comment: My requirement is to update a field in Parent record when Child record is inserted.
In Apex I am performing the logic to calculate value to assign to a field in Parent Record and I am returning this field value in method using list<string>. This is output of the first element (Apex) in Flow. After that I am assigning this value to Parent record and updating it.This is the whole flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few days analysis I found the reason of this error. Invocable method should not be void method. It should return something. After changed the return type this flow apex supports to insert upto 200 records. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on this? Seems somewhat unexpected ...